# Export / import

Tags: multisite, import, icon

I have a GeneratePress theme website on a multisite wordpress and I am having a problem with duplicating the site.

Everything is imported correctly, but one field is always missing after import - Icons http://prntscr.com/vut1f6

On the original version that I made an export from, there is a link to an external icon source. All links from this field disapear when I import the site to a new domain.

Can anyone help so I can avoid editing every icon after duplicating my website?

Thank you.

Comment: What are you using to duplicate and import the site? I don't recognise that field (but I don't know the editor well): was it added by GeneratePress or another plugin?

Comment: I am using wordpress importer and generate press settings import. I am not sure how was it added, It was in original Generatepress template I used to build the site.